# How to access elements in the list by buttons going back and forth kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I have two arrows left and right and a text view in the middle (Image below). Users can access the date from the list by pressing the buttons back and forth. Is there a better implementation to solve this problem? My solution:[image]

```
//The date repeats every 4 weeks
val d = LocalDate.of(2023, 2, 10)
val f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
val futurePayDate = d.plusWeeks(4).format(f)

paydayTextView.text = futurePayDate.toString()

val arrowright = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButtonArrowRight)
val arrowleft = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButtonArrowLeft)

val g = listOf<String>(
    d.plusWeeks(4).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(8).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(12).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(16).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(20).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(24).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(28).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(32).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(36).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(40).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(44).format(f),
    d.plusWeeks(48).format(f)
)

var indexright = 0
arrowright.setOnClickListener {

    if (indexright == 12) {
        val end = "The End!"
        paydayTextView.text = end
    } else {
        paydayTextView.text = g[indexright]
        indexright += 1
    }
}

arrowleft.setOnClickListener {
       
    if (indexright == 12) {
        paydayTextView.text = g[g.lastIndex]
        indexright -= 1
    }
    else if (indexright == 1){
        val end = "The End!"
        paydayTextView.text = end
    } else {
        indexright -= 1
        paydayTextView.text = g[g.lastIndex - (g.size - indexright)]
    }
}
```

Comment: Open-ended/opinion-based questions like this are off-topic for Stack Overflow. This might be a good fit for the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site, but be sure to read their rules before posting there.

Comment: One-liner equivalent to your list initialization: `val g = (4..48 step 4).map { d.plusWeeks(it).format(f) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of tracking `indexRight` you could track `currentIndex` instead, and have the click listeners call a function to update that value. Then the function can do things like validate the index, enable/disable buttons (so you can't click right when you're on the last item, instead of showing "the end") and display the current item. So your function handles setting and displaying the current UI state. Something like this:

```
private var currentIndex = 0

...

arrowLeft.setOnClickListener { setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1) }
arrowRight.setOnClickListener { setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1) }

...

// this could be a setter on the currentIndex property if you like,
// so it can only be updated by going through this function (and its validation)
fun setCurrentIndex(index: Int) {
    // handle whatever validation here, e.g. ignore bad values, fail etc
    require(index in g.indices)

    currentIndex = index
    // enable/disable buttons as appropriate
    arrowLeft.enabled = index != 0
    arrowRight.enabled = index != g.lastIndex

    // display your data
    paydayTextView.text = g[index]
}
```

The nice thing about doing things this way is it's easy to restore the UI state - you can store the current index, and just call this setter function during `onCreate` or whatever to set everything back up. Your left and right buttons are basically just doing the same thing, calling that *set the current index* function, but with an incremented/decremented value.

(You *can* do the *"the end"* thing instead of preventing the user from clicking past the first/last item, but you might want to add those to your list as elements and add some logic to prevent the user from actually using them. I feel like not allowing them to move to an invalid position in the first place is more intuitive and familiar, though!)